# Application Server error - No terminal found for MachineID on IIS

Tags: c#, rest, iis, iis-express, webapi

I have a web API developed in C# and it runs with no error on Visual Studio with IIS Express.
Now that the application is done I have deploy it to IIS but on the same machine.
With the previous web API I have no problem, bu with this one it gives me the following error:

> No terminal found for MachineID: ServerName

[image]

I have search on the internet and I haven't found any matter related to this problem.

The server I am using is a windows server 2012 R2 and IIS 8
The application pool I am using is .net v.45

I have tried different configurations regarding the initialising of the API and it's components.
Also try to change the AppPool pipeline mode.

Comment: Running in VS/IIS Express is completely different from running on full IIS, so you need to carefully review the code base to eliminate any invalid assumption, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, please check the console or Event Viewer for related error messages, and please translate your error messages into English.